# slack api rtm.start missing_scope needed client

Tags: slack-api

I have get access token and when I try to post rtm.start, I am getting below error:

```
{
    error = "missing_scope";
    needed = client;
    ok = 0;
    provided = "identify,read,post";
}
```

I have set the scope to `read,post,identify` in authorize API. I have read the API document over and over again. Only `rtm.start` mentioned client scope. But in oauth document I didn't find a client scope. So, what's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to do it before you get the token.

when you do the initial request to connect the app, include `&scope="identify,read,post,client"`

Comment: I read the docs, and the client is not in the scope. It worked. Thanks .

Comment: If you print the body of the response, it will tell you what scope is missing: e.g. `{"ok":false,"error":"missing_scope","needed":"users:read","provided":"identify,team:read"}`

Comment: @hailgrail I can't find client in the Scopes section of creating a new app. Any idea?

Comment: "you have to do it before you get the token." Where?

Comment: Add permissions regarding this link: https://api.slack.com/messaging/files/setup#upload_scopes

Answer (score 4):

Under App Credentials get your Client ID and Client Secret.
Goto:

```
https://#{team}.slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=#{cid}&scope=client
```

replacing #{team} and #{cid} with your values.

When you approve the authorization you’ll goto that real url that doesn’t resolve. Copy the whole url to your clipboard and paste it into a text file. Extract out just the “code” part.

Now goto:

```
https://#{team}.slack.com/api/oauth.access?client_id=#{cid}&client_secret=#{cs}&code=#{code}"
```

And you’ll get back a token like:
xoxp-4422442222–3111111111–11111111118–11aeea211e

(from here: https://medium.com/@andrewarrow/how-to-get-slack-api-tokens-with-client-scope-e311856ebe9)